# Spark Will Not Load Large MySql Table: Java Communications link failure - Timing Out

Tags: apache-spark, jdbc, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, databricks

I'm trying to get a pretty large table from mysql so I can manipulate using spark/databricks.  I can't get it to load into spark - I have tried taking smaller subsets, but even at the smallest reasonable unit, it still fails to load.

I have tried playing with the wait_timeout and interactive_timeout in mysql, but it doesn't seem to make any difference

I am also loading a smaller (different) table, and that loads just fine.

```
df_dataset = get_jdbc('raw_data_load', predicates=predicates).select('field1','field2', 'field3','date')

df_dataset = df_dataset.repartition('date')                                                                                      
df_dataset.registerTempTable('raw_data')
```

I then am trying to cache the data for sql purposes using

```
%sql

cache table raw_data;
```

And it goes and chugs for a while and his the database, but always times out after 30-40 minutes and I get the error below

Up until the point it times out, I see

```
Error in SQL statement: SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 30.0 failed 4 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.3 in stage 30.0 (TID 17075, 10.200.240.63, executor 1): com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure

The last packet successfully received from the server was 1,715,280 milliseconds ago.  The last packet sent successfully to the server was 1,715,290 milliseconds ago.
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:411)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createCommunicationsException(SQLError.java:1121)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.nextRowFast(MysqlIO.java:2290)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.nextRow(MysqlIO.java:2046)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.readSingleRowSet(MysqlIO.java:3554)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.getResultSet(MysqlIO.java:491)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.readResultsForQueryOrUpdate(MysqlIO.java:3245)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.readAllResults(MysqlIO.java:2413)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2836)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2825)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeInternal(PreparedStatement.java:2156)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeQuery(PreparedStatement.java:2323)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JDBCRDD.compute(JDBCRDD.scala:301)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:323)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:287)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:323)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:287)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:323)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$8.apply(RDD.scala:336)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$8.apply(RDD.scala:334)
    at org.apache.spark.storage.BlockManager$$anonfun$doPutIterator$1.apply(BlockManager.scala:1005)
    at org.apache.spark.storage.BlockManager$$anonfun$doPutIterator$1.apply(BlockManager.scala:996)
    at org.apache.spark.storage.BlockManager.doPut(BlockManager.scala:936)
    at org.apache.spark.storage.BlockManager.doPutIterator(BlockManager.scala:996)
    at org.apache.spark.storage.BlockManager.getOrElseUpdate(BlockManager.scala:700)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.getOrCompute(RDD.scala:334)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:285)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:323)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:287)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:323)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:287)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:323)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:287)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:96)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:53)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:99)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:322)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.io.EOFException: Can not read response from server. Expected to read 10 bytes, read 4 bytes before connection was unexpectedly lost.
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.readFully(MysqlIO.java:3166)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.nextRowFast(MysqlIO.java:2271)
    ... 42 more

Driver stacktrace:
com.databricks.backend.common.rpc.DatabricksExceptions$SQLExecutionException: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 30.0 failed 4 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.3 in stage 30.0 (TID 17075, 10.200.240.63, executor 1): com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure

The last packet successfully received from the server was 1,715,280 milliseconds ago.  The last packet sent successfully to the server was 1,715,290 milliseconds ago.
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:411)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createCommunicationsException(SQLError.java:1121)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.nextRowFast(MysqlIO.java:2290)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.nextRow(MysqlIO.java:2046)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.readSingleRowSet(MysqlIO.java:3554)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.getResultSet(MysqlIO.java:491)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.readResultsForQueryOrUpdate(MysqlIO.java:3245)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.readAllResults(MysqlIO.java:2413)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2836)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2825)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeInternal(PreparedStatement.java:2156)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeQuery(PreparedStatement.java:2323)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JDBCRDD.compute(JDBCRDD.scala:301)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:323)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:287)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:323)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:287)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:323)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$8.apply(RDD.scala:336)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$8.apply(RDD.scala:334)
    at org.apache.spark.storage.BlockManager$$anonfun$doPutIterator$1.apply(BlockManager.scala:1005)
    at org.apache.spark.storage.BlockManager$$anonfun$doPutIterator$1.apply(BlockManager.scala:996)
    at org.apache.spark.storage.BlockManager.doPut(BlockManager.scala:936)
    at org.apache.spark.storage.BlockManager.doPutIterator(BlockManager.scala:996)
    at org.apache.spark.storage.BlockManager.getOrElseUpdate(BlockManager.scala:700)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.getOrCompute(RDD.scala:334)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:285)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:323)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:287)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:323)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:287)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:323)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:287)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:96)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:53)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:99)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:322)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.io.EOFException: Can not read response from server. Expected to read 10 bytes, read 4 bytes before connection was unexpectedly lost.
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.readFully(MysqlIO.java:3166)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.nextRowFast(MysqlIO.java:2271)
    ... 42 more

Driver stacktrace:
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.org$apache$spark$scheduler$DAGScheduler$$failJobAndIndependentStages(DAGScheduler.scala:1442)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1430)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1429)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray$class.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:59)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:48)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.abortStage(DAGScheduler.scala:1429)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:803)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:803)
    at scala.Option.foreach(Option.scala:257)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.handleTaskSetFailed(DAGScheduler.scala:803)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.doOnReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1657)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1612)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1601)
    at org.apache.spark.util.EventLoop$$anon$1.run(EventLoop.scala:48)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.runJob(DAGScheduler.scala:628)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:1937)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:1950)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:1963)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:1977)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$collect$1.apply(RDD.scala:936)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:112)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.withScope(RDD.scala:362)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.collect(RDD.scala:935)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.executeCollect(SparkPlan.scala:275)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$$anonfun$count$1.apply(Dataset.scala:2409)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$$anonfun$count$1.apply(Dataset.scala:2408)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$$anonfun$60.apply(Dataset.scala:2791)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$$anonfun$withNewExecutionId$1.apply(SQLExecution.scala:87)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withFileAccessAudit(SQLExecution.scala:53)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withNewExecutionId(SQLExecution.scala:70)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.withAction(Dataset.scala:2790)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.count(Dataset.scala:2408)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.CacheTableCommand.run(cache.scala:45)
    at com.databricks.sql.acl.TrustedRunnableCommand$$anonfun$run$1.apply(TrustedRunnableCommand.scala:29)
    at com.databricks.sql.acl.TrustedRunnableCommand$$anonfun$run$1.apply(TrustedRunnableCommand.scala:29)
    at com.databricks.sql.acl.CheckPermissions$.trusted(CheckPermissions.scala:460)
    at com.databricks.sql.acl.TrustedRunnableCommand.run(TrustedRunnableCommand.scala:29)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.ExecutedCommandExec.sideEffectResult$lzycompute(commands.scala:58)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.ExecutedCommandExec.sideEffectResult(commands.scala:56)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.ExecutedCommandExec.executeCollect(commands.scala:67)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.<init>(Dataset.scala:185)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$.ofRows(Dataset.scala:64)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.sql(SparkSession.scala:599)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext.sql(SQLContext.scala:698)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.SQLDriverLocal$$anonfun$1.apply(SQLDriverLocal.scala:82)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.SQLDriverLocal$$anonfun$1.apply(SQLDriverLocal.scala:28)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:234)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:234)
    at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:381)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$class.map(TraversableLike.scala:234)
    at scala.collection.immutable.List.map(List.scala:285)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.SQLDriverLocal.executeSql(SQLDriverLocal.scala:28)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.SQLDriverLocal.repl(SQLDriverLocal.scala:128)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.DriverLocal$$anonfun$execute$2.apply(DriverLocal.scala:230)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.DriverLocal$$anonfun$execute$2.apply(DriverLocal.scala:211)
    at com.databricks.logging.UsageLogging$$anonfun$withAttributionContext$1.apply(UsageLogging.scala:173)
    at scala.util.DynamicVariable.withValue(DynamicVariable.scala:58)
    at com.databricks.logging.UsageLogging$class.withAttributionContext(UsageLogging.scala:168)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.DriverLocal.withAttributionContext(DriverLocal.scala:39)
    at com.databricks.logging.UsageLogging$class.withAttributionTags(UsageLogging.scala:206)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.DriverLocal.withAttributionTags(DriverLocal.scala:39)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.DriverLocal.execute(DriverLocal.scala:211)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.DriverWrapper$$anonfun$tryExecutingCommand$2.apply(DriverWrapper.scala:589)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.DriverWrapper$$anonfun$tryExecutingCommand$2.apply(DriverWrapper.scala:589)
    at scala.util.Try$.apply(Try.scala:192)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.DriverWrapper.tryExecutingCommand(DriverWrapper.scala:584)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.DriverWrapper.executeCommand(DriverWrapper.scala:488)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.DriverWrapper.runInnerLoop(DriverWrapper.scala:391)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.DriverWrapper.runInner(DriverWrapper.scala:348)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.DriverWrapper.run(DriverWrapper.scala:215)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure

The last packet successfully received from the server was 1,715,280 milliseconds ago.  The last packet sent successfully to the server was 1,715,290 milliseconds ago.
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:411)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createCommunicationsException(SQLError.java:1121)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.nextRowFast(MysqlIO.java:2290)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.nextRow(MysqlIO.java:2046)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.readSingleRowSet(MysqlIO.java:3554)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.getResultSet(MysqlIO.java:491)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.readResultsForQueryOrUpdate(MysqlIO.java:3245)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.readAllResults(MysqlIO.java:2413)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2836)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2825)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeInternal(PreparedStatement.java:2156)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeQuery(PreparedStatement.java:2323)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JDBCRDD.compute(JDBCRDD.scala:301)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:323)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:287)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:323)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:287)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:323)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$8.apply(RDD.scala:336)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$8.apply(RDD.scala:334)
    at org.apache.spark.storage.BlockManager$$anonfun$doPutIterator$1.apply(BlockManager.scala:1005)
    at org.apache.spark.storage.BlockManager$$anonfun$doPutIterator$1.apply(BlockManager.scala:996)
    at org.apache.spark.storage.BlockManager.doPut(BlockManager.scala:936)
    at org.apache.spark.storage.BlockManager.doPutIterator(BlockManager.scala:996)
    at org.apache.spark.storage.BlockManager.getOrElseUpdate(BlockManager.scala:700)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.getOrCompute(RDD.scala:334)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:285)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:323)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:287)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:323)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:287)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:323)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:287)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:96)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:53)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:99)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:322)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    ... 1 more
Caused by: java.io.EOFException: Can not read response from server. Expected to read 10 bytes, read 4 bytes before connection was unexpectedly lost.
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.readFully(MysqlIO.java:3166)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.nextRowFast(MysqlIO.java:2271)
    ... 42 more

    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.SQLDriverLocal.executeSql(SQLDriverLocal.scala:116)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.SQLDriverLocal.repl(SQLDriverLocal.scala:128)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.DriverLocal$$anonfun$execute$2.apply(DriverLocal.scala:230)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.DriverLocal$$anonfun$execute$2.apply(DriverLocal.scala:211)
    at com.databricks.logging.UsageLogging$$anonfun$withAttributionContext$1.apply(UsageLogging.scala:173)
    at scala.util.DynamicVariable.withValue(DynamicVariable.scala:58)
    at com.databricks.logging.UsageLogging$class.withAttributionContext(UsageLogging.scala:168)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.DriverLocal.withAttributionContext(DriverLocal.scala:39)
    at com.databricks.logging.UsageLogging$class.withAttributionTags(UsageLogging.scala:206)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.DriverLocal.withAttributionTags(DriverLocal.scala:39)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.DriverLocal.execute(DriverLocal.scala:211)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.DriverWrapper$$anonfun$tryExecutingCommand$2.apply(DriverWrapper.scala:589)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.DriverWrapper$$anonfun$tryExecutingCommand$2.apply(DriverWrapper.scala:589)
    at scala.util.Try$.apply(Try.scala:192)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.DriverWrapper.tryExecutingCommand(DriverWrapper.scala:584)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.DriverWrapper.executeCommand(DriverWrapper.scala:488)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.DriverWrapper.runInnerLoop(DriverWrapper.scala:391)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.DriverWrapper.runInner(DriverWrapper.scala:348)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.DriverWrapper.run(DriverWrapper.scala:215)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Answer (score 0):

With extremely large tables you're going to want to partition the query across your executors. By default the JDBC reader will read the query the parallelize it from the driver. If you have an incrementing, sequential key in the table you can parallelize using the `lowerBound`, `upperBound`, and `numPartitions` parameters. Here's an example taken from https://docs.databricks.com/spark/latest/data-sources/sql-databases.html#python-example

```
df = spark.read.\
      jdbc(url=jdbcUrl, \
              table='employees',\
              column='emp_no',\
              lowerBound=1,\
              upperBound=100000, \
              numPartitions=100)
df.show()
```

Having said that, you may want to read and write the data out to Parquet as that will perform better than re-reading from JDBC again.

Comment: is there a way to partition it on a "date" field? That seems the most logical way to split based on what I'm doing..  Thanks

Comment: The lowerBound and upperBound values must be longs, so if the date is in unix time then that should work, yes.

Comment: @StumblingThroughDataScience please accept the response as the selected answer if it resolves your issue, thanks!

Comment: Just trying to figure out if this works- my field is a date field, not a Unix timestamp

Comment: @StumblingThroughDataScience you could try using a query (vs table) with `.option("dbtable", "(select * from table)")` and convert the date to a number with either `UNIX_TIMESTAMP` or `DATE_FORMAT`. However you should check the MySQL query plan to ensure you're not going to incur a full table scan for each partitioned query.